# How do I get a list of all done TODOs?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

A while ago I started using org-mode to track TODOs in various files. Some of them were archived later. I have it set up so that a timestamp is saved with the TODO when it is closed.

Now, I want to review what I've done. I need a list of all of them that are in DONE state, preferably ordered by timestamp.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: In agenda, `v L` to view the log. `v A` to add archived files.

Comment: No: @mankoff should make an answer out of his comment with a reference to the pertaining manual section...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html

In agenda, `v L` to view the log. `v A` to add archived files.